# Spark UDF - Return type DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a UDF which will add a column flag in DataFrame and return new dataFrame.

```
def find_mismatch = udf((df: DataFrame) => {
df.withColumn("Flag",when(df("T_RTR_NUM").isNull && df("P_RTR_NUM").isNull , 
"Present in Flex but missing Trn and Platform"))

}
)
```

I am able to create UDF but when I pass a DataFrame into this , it gets errored out.
It works with normal function but when it comes to Spark UDF , it gets errored out.

Also, help me in understanding what difference will it make If I use normal function instead of spark UDF.

Please help. I have attached screenshot of code.
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as code formatted text and not as a picture.

Comment: What you are trying to do shouldn't be a UDF and UDF don't take a DataFrame in argument. Otherwise please don't post screenshots but actually code.

Comment: Why you need udf for it? You can pass this to a normal function like def getTransfered(df:Dataset[Row]]:Dataset[Row]={//operations}

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a DataFrame to a UDF as a DataFrame is handled by a spark context i.e. at the driver and you can't pass that along to a UDF which runs on the different executors (and only hold a fraction of a dataframe)

Specifically about the problem you're trying to solve - as  mentioned by @Manoj you don't actually need to use a UDF to get the result you need

Comment: What difference it makes by using UDF and normal function. In terms of performance and its execution at worker nodes.

Comment: these are two different things - a normal function (in the context of spark) is just a way to structure the code (which runs on the driver or that is used to generate spark's execution plans) . A UDF is a code closure that would be deployed and run on the executors

Comment: Is there any way, I can build similar spark sql UDF to make sure code runs in executor. I want to generalize a code to add a column to DF and return it back.

Comment: adding a column is not something you'd do in a UDF (do note that spark's withColumn command will run in parallel in the executors but it is declared and managed from the driver)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `udf` like below

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    def findMismatch(df:Dataset[Row]):Dataset[Row]={
    val transDF=df.withColumn("Flag",when(df("T_RTR_NUM").isNull && df("P_RTR_NUM").isNull ,"Present in Flex but missing Trn and Platform"))

    transDF
    }

    val transDF=findMismatch(df)
```